# Host low-trust app on IIS Website for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, authentication, azure

I'm working on a thesis regarding SharePoint Online and apps.

I thought it is possible to deploy a low-trust app to a local IIS website and make in accessible from SharePoint Online. However, I can't really find a way to make an IIS website compatible with the Azure ACS.

Is there anyone who can confirm if a low-trust app can be deployed to a local IIS website while it has to become accessible by SharePoint Online, and if so, can explain what has to be done to the IIS website to make it's authentication compatible with Azure ACS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is definitely possible is to deploy a low-trust add-in package to an on-premises farm using a local IIS web site as provider and Azure ACS for authorization. Did this, it works.

What got me started is this PnP resource: [SharePoint.LowTrustACS.Configuration](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Scripts/SharePoint.LowTrustACS.Configuration)

Making an "app accessible from SharePoint Online" sounds like the easier approach where an app package is deployed to SharePoint Online that uses your IIS web site as the "provider" part. The IIS web site must be accessible from the internet in this case. This approach is "easier", because you don't have to teach an on-premises farm to talk to ACS.